# ¿Cómo cambiar el fragment inicial de mi gráfico de navegación?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragment, navigation

Estoy usando `Navigate component`, tengo mi `nav_graph` en la cual están mis fragmentos. Quiero hacer mi app **Single Activity** con muchos fragmentos.

No se me ocurre como hacer lo siguiente: Cuando recién descargues la `app` que ajustes algunas configuraciones y que después te lleve a la `main activity` que será la pantalla de inicio.

Tengo entendido que con el gráfico de navegación se elije que fragmento iniciará la `app`. Pero, ¿y cómo hago para cuando el usuario ya se haya registrado y la `app` deba iniciarse en la pantalla de inicio?

Los fragmentos que se ven son los de la configuración de la cuenta. Actualmente el fragmento intro que es con el que iniciaría esta siendo *hosteado* por la `main activity`.

Reitero, ¿cómo hago que para hacer lo que explique con anterioridad?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según los [principios de navegación](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles), la start destination nunca debe ser una pantalla de login, configuración o tutorial. La start destination tiene que ser la pantalla con la que los usuarios inician su flujo normal y no debería cambiarse. Esto optimiza la carga de tu app para el caso más frecuente que es cuando el usuario ya se ha registrado.

En tu mainFragment puedes evaluar todas las condiciones que necesites y por ejemplo, redirigir al usuario a la pantalla de configuración si no se ha registrado

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    if (!isUserRegistered()) findNavController().navigate(R.id.intro)
    ...
}
```

Esto se llama *conditional navigation* y puedes encontrar un ejemplo completo en la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional).